# Solaris Commands

Tags: solaris

Any reference to solaris commands, I need to check some solaris LDOM for various parameters, so need the list of solaris commands.

Comment: Which version of Solaris?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link to [Solaris man pages](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=solaris11) and other documentation.

Comment: Sorry folks but need some conclusion for the command below:
"/app (/dev/dsk/c0d1s0   ):51430396 blocks  3098364 files"
What is the size of UFS in the command above; does block means the total space allocation?

Comment: That's not a command, that's output from some command, probably df, but you're making us guess, which is a horrible way to get help.

You'll probably find df -k or df -h gives output closer to what you expect.

Answer (score 5):

[Rosetta Stone for Unix](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) is an excellent reference for *nix systems when you are familiar with how to perform operations in one flavour of *nix but need to work on an unfamiliar distribution.

Comment: I've also found the "Solaris Infrequently Asked And Obscure Questions (IAOQ)" helpful when dealing with solaris boxes: http://www.columbia.edu/~rtt2101/iaoq/